# Piped MySQL Logging

Tags: mysql

I am trying to have mysql transaction logging goto a script and the from the script I am writing the file to two locations (one mapped remote) for basic redundancy and possibly for extension/specialized parsing later.

With some applications I am able to use a pipe to the script i.e. --`log="|/usr/local/bin/processScript"`

MySQL however complains it is not able to find the file even with 755 permissions on the script.

I have also looked at FIFO files but I am not sure if they can do what I want to do. I really don't want to use any form of polling system.

Any ideas on what might be going on, or how to achieve this?

Comment: What version of MySQL? 5.0 (Surprisingly common version)? 5.1?

Comment: 5.0.77 is the version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `|/path/to/some/script` syntax for output destination is application specific. Some applications support may it. [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/query-log.html) says nothing about supporting this syntax, so probably it is not supported.

For redundancy you should use MySQL built-in replication. Additionally, you could enable [`log-slave-updates`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_log-slave-updates) option and extract executed queries from binlog on slave using mysqlbinlog.

Another posibility is setting up [DRBD replication](http://www.drbd.org/home/what-is-drbd/) on volume, where mysql general log is stored.

Answer (score 0):

i dont think it's possible. for redundancy - why don't you use regular mysql replication to other mysql servers located locally & offsite [with binlog to file enabled on them ... so you have the data even in case someone executes the dreaded drop table command ]?

Comment: Redundancy isn't the only reason. Might want to parse it into a different format at some point on the fly.

Comment: @Joshua Enfield - then - i'm affraid text logging and live tail'ing it or parsing of binlogs are your only options.

Answer (score 0):

Never seen a the logfile defined as a pipe before. Sure you can do that?

Also have you considered using binary logging? Much quicker! But means you have to deal with binary logs not plain text - the mysqlbinlog command will do most the work though.

Comment: Yes, it's worked for other applications see http://serverfault.com/questions/157044/linux-centos-is-there-any-feasible-way-to-add-a-file-write-hook